# Rectangle circumscribing a rectangle - size of inner rectangle

Tags: python, image-processing, rectangles, bounding-box

Suppose I have a rectangle circumscribing another rectangle.
The only parameters I have are X size, Y size and R - the ratio of the sides of the inner rectangle.

[image]

Is it possible to find the size of L (meaning the size of one side of the inner rectangle?)
If so, what will be the right formula?

Comment: If you don’t know the angle, then no.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's the solution in python:

1. How to find the angle
2. How to find L

```
def diagonal_calc(row):

    #parameters I have
    R = 1/(row.lw_ratio) 
    X = row.x_size
    Y = row.y_size

    #calculations

    #find alpha:
    equation1 = (((X/Y)*R)-1) / (R-(X/Y))
    alpha = math.degrees(math.tan(equation1))

    #find sides:
    sin_alpha = R*math.sin(np.deg2rad(alpha))
    cos_alpha = math.cos(np.deg2rad(alpha))

    L_side = X/((R*sin_alpha)  +  cos_alpha)
    RL_side = R*L_side


    return alpha, L_side, RL_side
```